# How to make repeating-linear-gradient fit font-size?

Tags: css, repeating-linear-gradient

I'm a noob in CSS, sorry if it's a simple thing.

I want to create a striped background for a textarea element (to make it look like a notepad). This can be achieved with the following CSS background rule:

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(white, white 0.9rem, black 0.9rem, black 1rem);
}
```

```html
<textarea><textarea>
```

The only problem is that, as can be seen above, as more lines are typed into the textarea, the stripes get out of sync and start to move upwards in relation to the text.

**Question**: How can I make the repeated stripes always fit perfectly with the font-size?

Comment: Setting a `font-size: 1rem` and `line-height: 1` gets somewhat close to what I think you want. The problem, which I don't know if you care to solve, is scrolling the text area, the text moves, the background does not.

Comment: @disinfor thanks for the tip, but I'm not sure I get what you mean. Others have also commented that the background does not move with the text, but testing this both in Firefox and Chromium I see the background moving together with the text as I scroll (just like a real notebook would be), so that each line is scrolled together with the text. Curiously, in Brett Donald's answer I do see the background fixed and not moving as I scroll (in Firefox, the text and background can even become misaligned if you scroll)

Comment: If you type anything in the `textarea` that overflows the vertical and extends the size of the element, the scroll will scroll the text and not the background - at least in the newest version of FF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `1lh` to get the height of one line

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0; /* there is a default padding */
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#0000 0 calc(1lh - 1px), #000 0 1lh);
  /* line-height: 1.5; use this to increase the height of the line */
}
```

```html
<textarea><textarea>
```

Comment: Off topic but as a supplement, `background-attachment:local` can help solving the background not moving with the text.

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly it! But if you don't mind an additional question, why are the correct values `(transparent 0 calc(1lh - 1px), black **0** 1lh)`? Shouldn't it be `black calc(1lh - 1px) 1lh` instead of `0`? Or does it mean that the second color (black) is also applied to the full `1lh`, but the first color (transparent) overrides the first color till `calc(1lh - 1px)`? It's not clear to me how the syntax works there

Comment: @flen *If a color stop or transition hint has a position that is less than the specified position of any color stop or transition hint before it in the list, set its position to be equal to the largest specified position of any color stop or transition hint before it.* --> https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#color-stop-fixup

Comment: @TemaniAfif This is the second answer today I've seen where you used `lh` units. I never knew those existed. Reading the spec on MDN, this may come in handy for future work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `lh` (line height) units for your linear gradient, and `background-attachment: local` to make the background scroll with the text.

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
  background: #eee;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35vh;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(white, white calc(1lh - 1px), #ccc calc(1lh - 1px), #ccc 1lh);
  background-attachment: local;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #d70000;
}

.ta1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.ta2 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="ta1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</textarea>

<textarea class="ta2">Cras volutpat velit non mi sagittis condimentum. Cras tempor aliquet turpis sed pretium. Nunc aliquet sodales turpis quis ultrices. Duis auctor accumsan enim, quis maximus ex malesuada a. Donec a felis ut erat tempus euismod non vel neque. Proin lectus massa, sagittis at imperdiet nec, consequat ut neque. Sed vel placerat neque, vel varius urna. Vivamus interdum euismod urna a accumsan. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</textarea>
```